# Spring Hibernate JPA - @Transactional does not Insert Data (Postgres)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm implementing a service layer with transactions, with all configuration handled in Java config.  The service transaction operates using JPA repositories.  The transaction executes fine, SQL is shown in the log (if I set Hibernate tracing), however no data is inserted into the database (Postgres.)  I'm not even receiving an exception when this occurs.  What's the best way to address this issue?  (simplified business logic below)

**ValueSetService.java**

```
public interface ValueSetService {
    void processValueSets(List<Code> codes);
}
```

**ValueSetServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class ValueSetServiceImpl implements ValueSetService {

    @Autowired
    private ValueSetRepository valueSetRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CodeRepository codeRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void processValueSets(List<Code> codes) 
    {
        for (Code code : codes)
        {
            codeRepository.save(code);
        }
    }

}
```

**JpaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.package.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.package.service"})
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager tm =
                new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        // tm.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return tm;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceManager() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyOverrideConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer() {
        PropertyOverrideConfigurer config = new PropertyOverrideConfigurer();
        config.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        config.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("jpa.db.properties"));
        return config;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public HikariDataSource mainDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy dataSource() {
        LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy dataSource = new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy();
        dataSource.setTargetDataSource(mainDataSource());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("puName");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"org.package.model.**"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter
                .setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties
                .setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
                "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.prefer_lo",
                "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/ehcache-model.xml");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**CodeRepository.java**

```
public interface CodeRepository extends JpaRepository<Code, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Code> {

}
```

**Code.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code", catalog = "dbname", schema = "application")
public class Code implements Cloneable, Serializable, IPojoGenEntity, ICode {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "codeCode_idGenerator")
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "code_id", nullable = false  )
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "codeCode_idGenerator", sequenceName = "dbname.application.code_id_seq", schema = "application", catalog = "dbname")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;

    }

    @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = true )
    @JoinColumn(name = "value_set_id", nullable = true )
    public ValueSet getValueSet() {
        return this.valueSet;

    }

}
```

**Sample Hibernate SQL output in Console**

```
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] DEBUG  insert into dbname.application.code (code_name, code_system_id, date_created, date_disabled, date_updated, description, user_created, user_updated, value_set_id, code_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) (SQL)
Hibernate: insert into dbname.application.code (code_name, code_system_id, date_created, date_disabled, date_updated, description, user_created, user_updated, value_set_id, code_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [447422004] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [39] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Apr 28 14:24:15 EDT 2015] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Apr 28 14:24:15 EDT 2015] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [Code name goes here] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [null] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [null] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [666] (BasicBinder)
[28/04/2015 14:24:15] TRACE  binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [67310] (BasicBinder)
```

Comment: where is the bean defination for : CodeRepository?

Comment: Added the definition for CodeRepository above.  The JPA repositories (and entity objects) were autogenerated using [hbnpojogen](https://github.com/wwadge/hbnpojogen)

Comment: Hope you have Code class annotated with @Entity or @ Table entity and mapped in your configuration.

Comment: Added Code.java entity class to the post (removed some of the code)

Comment: Buddy can you check if query is executing, by enabling the show sql = true in hibernate config file. Because role of transaction is just to ensure ACID properties, it has no relation to saving or not saving of object in DB.

Comment: Not a problem, added sample SQL being executed by Hibernate.  Querying and inserting data standalone with the JPA repositories works fine, however if it's being executed inside a @Transactional scope the data won't persist to postgres (in the transactional case, the SQL is still being logged to the console just not being executed against the database.)

Comment: Now the problem I can see it Transaction is not committing. Something is stopping it to commit.

Comment: Small guess you have a web application with bot a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both doing a `@ComponentScan` for the same classes, leading to 2 instances of a service, 1 being transactional, the other not transactional and the last is going to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused to a data outlier which essentially filled up the transaction logs while running (leading the application to essentially halt.)  Refactoring the process to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding tm.afterPropertiesSet(); like below or inject the entityManagerFactory in the constructor of JpaTransactionManager.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    tm.afterPropertiesSet();
    return tm;
}
```

Comment: I tried that option with no luck.  I also tried changing the transaction manager to HibernateTransactionManager and that didn't work either.

Comment: That won't work as Spring will automatically call the `afterPropertiesSet` method for you, calling it or not will not change.